Pass the exceptions to js-event
I have the issue to pass auth exceptions to the js-events.
By the default if I need to develope the custom logic for the auth validation, I go to FortifyServiceProvider and in the boot function call the Fortify::authenticateUsing method and
return $user;

if success or
throw ValidationException::withMessages(['login' => $isMessage ? $e->getMessage() : 'Server error']);

if fail.
The problem in the way of the returning exception. ValidationException::withMessages returns the exception to the validate html-element under some field. For example, login.
But my issue to return the exception to js-event, for example to toastr.
I need this waybecause I exclude authorization using login and password to make request to separate database.
